# Why NHibernate requires the entities methods to be virtual?

Tags: nhibernate

NHibernate requires your entities properties and methods to be marked as virtual to do all its magic.

While I don't know NHibernate internalities, it's understandable why the properties have to be virtual (those will be read/written through a proxy class), but... **why on earth my entities methods must also be virtual?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the same reasons. If your methods are not virtual, then NHibernate would not be able to initialize proxy.

Just consider following code:

```
public class A 
{
   private int _a;
   public virtual int A 
   { 
     get { return _a; }
     set { _a = value; } 
   }

   public void DoSomethingWithA() 
   {
       Console.WriteLine(_a);
   }
}
```

So, if you have a proxy object of `A` when you call `a.DoSomethingWithA();` it will access uninitialized `_a` field.

To avoid such situations, to be able to inject proxy initialization code NHibernate requires not private methods to be virtual.

Comment: Correct. And what's more, if we do **NOT** want ***"NHibernate ... to do all its magic"*** - we can make any property or method **non** virtual - and then we have to change the mapping `<class ... lazy="false" ... >`. So, either proxy with virtual members - or not. *(not discussing what's better or proper, just saying: virtual is a mut JUST for a proxy)*